# Use EntityFieldQuery to load by node ID

Tags: 7, database

How to use `EntityFieldQuery` to load the nodes based on `available` ***nids***. I tried,

```
$query->propertyCondition('nid', $nid);
```

and

```
$query->entityCondition('nid', $nid);
```

Both of the above didn't work. What would be the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no point doing that, use `node_load()` or `node_load_multiple()` instead (or `entity_load()`). EFQ exists to return you the IDs of entities, essentially so you can use them in an entity load function. If you already know the ID beforehand, then using EFQ is a waste of a database query.

To illustrate, if you were to add a `nid` condition to your query, then these:

```
->entityCondition('bundle', 'article') // ex. article
->propertyCondition('uid', $uid) // node written by a specific user
->propertyCondition('status', 1);
```

are all redundant, your query will just be:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')->propertyCondition('nid', $nid);
```

and the only useful data you'll get is the node ID, which you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Probably $query->propertyCondition('nid',$nid); will work for you. I use same to fetch node like.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article') // ex. article
      ->propertyCondition('uid', $uid) // node written by a specific user
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1); // published nodes
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: means you looking for multiple nodes?

Comment: Multiple nodes with the same ID? That's not possible...

Comment: that can be possible with $nids = array(1,2,3); node id and in propertyCondition pass $query->propertyCondition('nid', $nids, 'IN')

Comment: Possible, yes, but also a complete waste of time and resources. All an EFQ can return to you are the node IDs. If you already _have_ the node IDs, then you've just wasted a trip to the database for precisely nothing.

Comment: yes, thats true.

Comment: @clive, I agree it's not common but it's far from useless. In some fairly extensive operations I ended up with a subset of nids I had to further filter by content. I only needed the nodes of that subset that match the content criteria. So I add `->propertyCondition('nid', $nids, 'IN')` rather than selected ALL nodes that match the content restriction and then manually check if they are part of my subset.

Comment: @WardD.S. That's a separate query (semantically); you're filtering an existing list of node IDs by a value that only exists in the database, and in such a situation yes, you'd absolutely need to use a database query again. But that's a very specific requirement, it doesn't apply to what we were talking about in the previous comments which was using an EFQ just to reload the node ids you've already got, no further filtering

Comment: @Clive Yea - the question is quite vague but I assumed the original poster was in a similar situation as he mentioned "nids" (although re-reading, his example code uses `$nid`, so maybe I was wrong in that assumption). You're absolutely right the above answer is a redundant query, vgoradiya should have probably amended his answer to include his comment, using the `array(...), "IN"` query as that's the only practical usage and, in my opinion, the most correct answer to this question :)

Comment: Either way, +1s for you and the `array..in` comment. Those solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends. If your entity field query is only using entity property conditions (the columns in the node table), then you can use nid.

If you add a field condition, entity field query will change it's base table (e.g. the table referenced in the FROM part of the from part of the query to that table). In which case, since most fields are generalized between entities, and refer to ids as "entity_id" instead of "nid" or "uid", you will need to use that column name instead.

I have not tested this with just accessing entity properties, but I'm looking at an EFQ right now that's failing because I use "nid" instead of "entity_id".

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type','node');
$query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$query->propertyOrderBy('title', 'ASC');
$query->entityCondition('bundle','committee_tenure');
$query->propertyCondition('nid',$member_com_ids,'IN');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need to pass a node ID to `propertyCondition`.

```
$query->propertyCondition('nid', 886);
```

Comment: OP tried that and it didn't work. Like they wrote in their question. So...